# How do I solve Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to build a simple app from scratch. I am encountering an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of
>   object '#' at Module../src/app/about.js (bundle.js:2081) at
>   **webpack_require** (bundle.js:724)

**about.js**

```
var React = require("react");
var createReactClass = require("create-react-class");
import { Link } from "react-router";

var About = createReactClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
        <Link to={"/"}>Home</Link>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = About;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/app/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'        
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.1"
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

I think this has something to do with my `module.exports`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [You cannot mix import and module.exports](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039#issuecomment-273804003)

Comment: @Kobe I see do you know of an alternative way to avoid the error?

Comment: Use `export default About;` instead.

Comment: Or, at the top use `const { Link } = require("react-router");`

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but I would recommend learning react hooks rather than classes if you are new to react. They are much more simple to use..

Comment: `module.exports` is an object so your assignment does not work - you'll need to define a new property inside of the object like module.exports.About = About

Comment: @LenJoseph Can you please write your comment as answer? I think it worked

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for this but I see a new console error `warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component supplied to Route.`

Comment: That's a separate error; your question was about using `require()` vs. `import/export`. Check the docs for react-router and try fixing this yourself first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the file, instead of using `import` method, use this:

```
const { Link } = require("react-router");
```